# Unable to access Microsoft One Drive data through Microsoft Graph

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

After hours just trying to connect to the microsoft graph using node.js I am able to obtain a list of users, however, when I try to access anything from one drive, the same technique absolutely fails. Here is some code that works for fetching users..

```
await fetch.callApi("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", authResponse.accessToken);
```

^^ This works.

If I try to modify the url and bit to match the microsoft graph explorer the whole thing collapses.

```
await fetch.callApi("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/drive/root/children", authResponse.accessToken);
```

^^^ This does not and throws a 404 not found. Even thought the exact same URL works in the graph explorer.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Figured it out - need to grant '
Sites.FullControl.All' permissions to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the OneDrive using Graph you need to change the data in the following ways.

```
$endpoints['personal_drives'] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/drives";
```

So in your case it should work for

```
await fetch.callApi("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/drives", authResponse.accessToken);
```